# How to remove all content outside xml in a file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I search a command for keep only xml in  a file, but i don't know how to make this.

I have searched regex, i have found this regex for find my content. `(<msg>[\s\S]*?<\/msg>)`

But i don't say how to integrate in sed for make this command in my programm: sed regex > myfile. 
Or better delete directly each line not matching with my regex.

My file:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Multipart/Related;boundary=MIME_boundary;

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;

<msg><tag date="1557417027960" session="1697"><decision object="B04DWHEF" reliability="95" context="RO" x="796" y="371" width="89" height="18" direction="front"><jpeg></jpeg></decision></tag></msg>

Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary;
Content-ID: A;
Content-Length: 30217;

����Lavc57.89.100��C...
```

I want only this result:

```
<msg><tag date="1557417027960" session="1697"><decision object="B04DWHEF" reliability="95" context="RO" x="796" y="371" width="89" height="18" direction="front"><jpeg></jpeg></decision></tag></msg>
```

Comment: `$ grep "<.*>.*</.*>" file_name` should work.

Comment: THINK about what `[\s\S]` means and the difference between that and `[.]`. Beyond that, very few seds will understand `\s` or `\S` and none will understand `*?` (a perl-ism).

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: @alk Because my program is in C and execute regex with a system call but other solution with library C was possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you Shubham for the regex, my solution for find only xml without other content in the same line is:

```
grep -o "<.*>.*</.*>" file_name
```